# Is there a way to use a raspberry pi code and have it ran on a seperate device (Arduino UNO)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I have a Raspberry Pi that is connected to a INA219 current sensor that currently runs a python code that measures the Bus voltage, bus current, power, and shunt voltage of the Raspberry pi and stores it within a CSV file that runs 10 times per second until the user stops it (CTRL + C). I am trying to create a code on my Arduino so that the code on the raspberry pi can run on a separate device, which is the Arduino UNO. The code from the raspberry pi that I am trying to get to run on a separate device is attached below:

```
#Importing libraries
import csv
import time

from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError


SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1

read_ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) 
read_ina.configure()

  
def read_all():
    
    data = {}
    data['Bus Voltage'] = read_ina.voltage()
    data['Bus Current'] = read_ina.current()
    data['Power'] = read_ina.power()
    data['Shunt Voltage'] = read_ina.shunt_voltage()
    data ['Frequency'] = 0
    return data

    
with open('SensorData.csv', 'w') as f:
    data = read_all()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,
                            fieldnames = list (data.keys()))

    writer.writeheader()

    
    exit = False

    while not exit:
        try:
            writer.writerow(data)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            data = read_all()
            compute_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            data['Frequency'] = 1 / compute_time 
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit = True
```

Again, I am having a hard time with having it show on the Arduino UNO interface. I have the Arduino IDE installed on my Raspberry pi and have not had luck with such a code.

Comment: so you have to rewrite it to Arduino C++ using Arduino libraries. what problem do you have doing so?

Comment: Hi @Juraj I am having a problem with creating the c++ code for the arduino. I already have the code created in python on the raspberry pi, so I need to rewrite the code on arduino? In which it will call the measure of the raspberry pi from the ina219 ? I dont have a breadboard so I am also just confused on how I get it to display on the arduino if there is no interface on which it could be visibly seen on. In terms of the code for the arduino, is there a way that I could create a code that instead goes into the raspberry pi system and pulls the code from it instead of creating a fresh code?